# how to remove facebook share button underline

Tags: jquery, facebook, css

I put this auto generated facebook share button

```
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.kafiyedizini.com" data-type="box_count"></div>
```

[**to my website**](http://www.kafiyedizini.com)

but there is the text is underlined when I hover my mouse over it.

[**See the caps here**](http://i.hizliresim.com/wbNErd.png)

I don't want underlined text inside the facebook share button when mouse hovers it.

how to achieve this?

thank you.

Comment: does my answer solved your issue?

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja no its still same check my website

Comment: there is no parameter for hover on your site.plz update css again

Answer (score 0):

Simply add CSS class with property given below:

```
.pluginShareButtonLink a:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}
```

**Edit:**

I checked that it will not work since facebook button is coming inside `iframe` and you can not change style of `iframe` which is coming from another server.

Comment: I checked that it will not work since facebook button is coming inside iframe and you can not change style of iframe which is coming from another server. @user3466700

Comment: if you still want I can give you a heck for that @user3466700

Answer (score 0):

add

```
.fb-share-button {
   text-decoration:none;
 }
```

if it is applied already then use `text-decoration:none !important`

```
.fb-share-button {
   text-decoration:none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
a:hover{
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
a#u_0_1.pluginShareButtonLink
  {
    color:transparent !important;
   }
```

Comment: This should defintiely work! Please let me know if that works.